# How to show cookie value before page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

Good evening.

I have problem with cookie setting. I need to set cookie "shid" (user id) and use it already on first visit. Because it's one page website and I need that cookie value to one link. Visitor may click on "Start chat" link and it looks like this: `chat.php?user_id=<? echo $_COOKIE['shid']; ?>`. But on first visit is "shid" empty. How can I set that cookie already on first visit, that user won't have to refresh the page to use chat correctly?

Thank you!

Here is full code:

```
<?php
  $sid = mt_rand();

    $cookie_name = "shid";

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['shid'])) {
    setcookie("shid", $sid, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
}
?>

<a class="chat1" href="chat.php?user_id=<? echo $_COOKIE['shid']; ?>"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define it. `$_COOKIE['name'] = 'value';`

I've also used `isset()` to verify the array value exists before trying to output it (which will avoid a pesky E_NOTICE if it doesn't exist).

```
<?php
  $sid = mt_rand();

    $cookie_name = "shid";

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['shid'])) {
    $time = time()+60*60*24*100;
    setcookie("shid", $sid, $time, "/");
    $_COOKIE['shid'] = $time;
}
?>

<a class="chat1" href="chat.php?user_id=<? echo( isset( $_COOKIE['shid'] ) ? $_COOKIE['shid'] : '' ); ?>"></a>
```